# Unable to upgrade to Ef 6.0. Unable to find a version of 'Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF' that is compatible

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm issuing this command in the Package Manager Console..

PM> install-package EntityFramework -version 6.0.0

and it is giving me the error that it cannot find a version of the Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF package that is compatible (Shown at bottom). Here are the breeze packages I currently have installed:

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Full error...

Install-Package : Updating 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version o
f 'Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF' that is compatible with 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  EntityFramework -version 6.0.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/start-nuget

Comment: Here are the breeze packages/versions: Breeze.Client, Breeze.WebApi, .WebApi.Core, .WebApi.EF.  ...i've tried both 1.4.7 and 1.4.8 of these packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF/) has a requirement of EF < 6.0.  You'll need to remove that and use the new packages listed in the [Nuget Documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/start-nuget#current).

ie. Remove `Breeze.WebApi` and add `Breeze.WebApi2`